# Input checking for a valid double or int

Tags: .net, validation, f#, user-input

I am trying to make a method that takes a string and tries to parse it as either an int or a double based on the second parameter. My code looks correct, but gives me a type mismatch. Yet it looks like it they are the correct types...

I am looking to get a recommendation on how to fix it. Below is where I am so far.

```
let double = Type.GetType("System.Double")
let int32 = Type.GetType("System.Int32")

let rec checkinput input (msType:Type)= 
    //force them to give you a good number
    let ConsoleTrap parsed msType=
        if fst parsed then
            snd parsed //return the parsed value
        else //the parse failed
            Console.WriteLine "Enter a real number"
            let newInput = Console.ReadLine()
            checkinput newInput
    //do it slightly differently based on whether we want an int or double
    if msType = double then
        ConsoleTrap (Double.TryParse input) (double)

    else 
        ConsoleTrap (Int32.TryParse input) (int32)
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote, at least give an explanation...

Comment: "My code looks correct, but gives me a type mismatch." could be nice to have the actual error message ; although i think the problem is what type to return given that it can be two differents things (int or double)

Comment: expecting an a' but given a  b' -> 'a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at Tomas answer, I was able to get it to compile a different way, using box and then unbox.

```
let double = Type.GetType("System.Double")
let int32 = Type.GetType("System.Int32")

//takes the user input and forces them to enter a valid number
// can return either valid doubles or ints
let rec checkinput (input) (msType:Type)  = 
    //force them to give you a good number
    let ConsoleTrap (parsed: obj) (msType :Type)=
        let parsed = unbox parsed
        if fst parsed then
            snd parsed //return the parsed value
        else
            Console.WriteLine "Enter a real number"
            let newInput = Console.ReadLine()
            checkinput newInput msType
    //do it slightly differently based on whether we want an int or double
    if msType = double then
        let parsed = Double.TryParse input
        ConsoleTrap (box parsed) double

    else 
        let parsed = Int32.TryParse input
        ConsoleTrap (box parsed) int32
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the problem is that your recursive call inside `ConsoleTrap` is missing a parameter. You only give it `newInput`, but it also expects `msType`. You can change that line to:

```
checkinput newInput msType
```

Now, this is still not going to work, but we are closer. Now the problem is that it is not clear what the result of the function should be. In:

```
if msType = double then
    ConsoleTrap (Double.TryParse input) (double)
else 
    ConsoleTrap (Int32.TryParse input) (int32)
```

... the `true` branch returns `float` and the `false` branch returns `int`. So this is a type checking error. You can sort of workaround this by making the function `checkinput` generic and only handling `int` and `double` cases (but making it return `'T`). Then you can add unsafe `unbox`. The following will work:

```
let rec checkinput input : 'TResult = 
    //force them to give you a good number
    let inline doer parsed : 'TLocal =
        if fst parsed then
            snd parsed //return the parsed value
        else //the parse failed
            Console.WriteLine "Enter a real number"
            let newInput = Console.ReadLine()
            unbox<'TLocal> (checkinput newInput)
    //do it slightly differently based on whether we want an int or double
    if typeof<'TResult> = double then
        unbox<'TResult> (doer (Double.TryParse input))
    else 
        unbox<'TResult> (doer (Int32.TryParse input))
```

That said, now it is getting a bit ugly and so I would probably not want to use this sort of code. You might have more duplication without this, but with a bit of duplication, you can probably solve your original problem in a more readable way.

Comment: Is there a better way to make things implicitly generic as opposed to explicitly generic? I thought that was the point of F#.

Comment: You can certainly remove some of the annotations - but I would leave them in this case. Once you're dealing with `unbox`, things become quite dangerous :-). Using `unbox` is definitely out of the F# comfort zone - which is why I'd consider writing the code differently.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to give it a go and ended with two different kind of things.
The first relies on "[duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)".

```
let inline checkInput input =
  let parsed = ref Unchecked.defaultof<_>

  let rec aux input =
    if (^a : (static member TryParse : string * ^a byref -> bool) (input, &parsed.contents)) then
      !parsed
    else
      Console.WriteLine "Enter a real number"
      aux (Console.ReadLine ())

  aux input

// usage
let n = checkInput<int> (Console.ReadLine ())
// let n : int = checkInput (Console.ReadLine ()) // equivalent syntax
let d = checkInput<double> (Console.ReadLine ())
// works for any type with a matching TryParse member
let dt = checkInput<DateTime> (Console.ReadLine ())
```

The second one relies on [discriminated union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx).

```
type ParseType = IntType | DoubleType
type ParseResult = IntResult of int | DoubleResult of double

// (note "input" arg could be η-converted)
let checkInput pType input =
  let rec aux parser resultCtor input =
    match parser input with
      true, parsed -> resultCtor parsed
    | _ ->
      Console.WriteLine "Enter a real number"
      aux parser resultCtor (Console.ReadLine ())

  // use the function associated with given "type case"
  match pType with
    IntType    -> aux Int32.TryParse IntResult input
  | DoubleType -> aux Double.TryParse DoubleResult input

// usage
let n = checkInput IntType (Console.ReadLine ())
let d = checkInput DoubleType (Console.ReadLine ())
```